# Gradle build error on previously working program

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, gradle

I have a Jave 8, SpringBoot, webService which has been running fine on Eclipse 2020-06 for months.  I build using Gradle. In an attempt to get the latest version of an updated jar file from Artifactory I did :

```
gradlew clean
gradlew eclipse
F5 (Refresh)
```

This indeed pulled the required jar file but my program now failed to compile. The error is:

```
The import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation cannot be resolved
```

And all my @Autowired commands now error.
What i've tried :

1. gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse
2. close project, close eclipse, reopen eclipse, reopen project
3. gradle -> Refresh Gradle project
4. Same a 2. preceded by reboot pc. When I do this I get:
   [image]

After I did:

```
gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse
```

The following jar dissapeared from my project:

```
spring-beans.5.3.0.RC1.jar
```

This is what is causing the problem.
Is this incorrect in build.gradle:

```
implementation "org.springframework:spring-beans:5.+"
```

How do I get this jar back?
Any help appreciated.
My build.gradle file is:

```
    plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
   maven {
       url "https://repo-int.xxxxxx.io/artifactory/cc-central"
   }
   maven {
       url "https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo"
   }
   maven {
            url "${chemaxonRepositoryUrl}/libs-release"
            credentials {
                username = chemaxonRepositoryUser
                password = chemaxonRepositoryPassword
            }
        }
}


ext {
    archive_basename = "dcrws"
    project_description = "Chemistry Workbench DcrWs"
    springStarterVersion = '2.2.2.RELEASE'

    // Jenkins/Environment Information
    build_tag = System.getenv('BUILD_TAG') ?: "none"
    build_by = System.getenv('NODE_NAME') ?: "none"
    build_date = System.getenv('BUILD_TIMESTAMP') ?: "none"
    build_system = System.getenv('JENKINS_HOME') ?: "none"
    build_url = System.getenv('BUILD_URL') ?: "none"
    build_user = System.getenv('USER') ?: "none"
}                    

// standard plugins
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

def git_info = hasProperty('git_info') ? git_info : 'https://git.git/repo,00000000'
def full_version = hasProperty('app_version') ? app_version : '0.0.0'

group = 'com.clarivate.singularity.chemworkbench'
version = full_version
archivesBaseName = ext.archive_basename

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8


configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

// if master branch, use latest version of chemcur:cwbcommon, else use 0.0+ version
ext.cwbcommon_version = '1.+'
if ( full_version =~ /^0./) { ext.cwbcommon_version = '0.0+' }
ext.pwbcommon_version = '1.+'
if ( full_version =~ /^0./) { ext.pwbcommon_version = '0.0+' }

dependencies {

    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:$springStarterVersion"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springStarterVersion"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:$springStarterVersion"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc:$springStarterVersion"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:$springStarterVersion"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:$springStarterVersion"
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.+'
    implementation "org.springframework:spring-beans:5.+"
    implementation "org.springframework:spring-core:5.+"
    implementation "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.+"
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9+"
    implementation "commons-dbutils:commons-dbutils:1.7+"
    implementation "com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.1.0"
    compile 'com.chemaxon:calculations:20.+'

    // homegrown libs
    compile ("chemcur:cwbcommon:${cwbcommon_version}")  {changing = true}
    compile ("chemcur:pwbcommon:${pwbcommon_version}")  {changing = true}

    developmentOnly "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:$springStarterVersion"
}


springBoot {
    buildInfo {
        properties {
            artifact = archive_basename
            version = full_version
            group = group
            name = project_description
            additional = [
                'Implementation-Title': project_description,
                'Implementation-Version': full_version,
                "Implementation-SCM": git_info,
                "Jenkins-Build-Tag": build_tag,
                "Build-By": build_by,
                "Build-Date": build_date,
                "Build-JDK": System.getProperty('java.version'),
                "Build-Gradle-Version": project.gradle.gradleVersion,
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to make this work outside eclipse and once the build is complete, check what's wrong with eclipse configuration. Also try deleting .gradle folder and do a clean build.

Comment: Can you provide your project through github ?

Comment: Add the following to build.gradle ? : compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.+'

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry anish B, i'm not allowed to do that

Comment: @sreehari Which .gradle folder should I delete, I have several. 1. within the project folder, 2. at the project folder level 3. Under "users/username" where all my referenced jars are stored?

Comment: It seems `gradlew eclipse` broke it. What did you want to achieve with this command? Can you restore the `.classpath` and `.project` file?

Comment: @howlger I mentioned that in the question, I was trying to pull an updated jar file from artifactory into my project. I can restore the .project and .classpath file, i'll give it a go

Comment: @DS. So you did `gradlew eclipse` instead of right-clicking the project and choosing _Grade > Refresh Gradle Project_? Please note, _Refresh_ (F5) and _Grade > Refresh Gradle Project_ are different things (F5 is to sync with the file system).

Comment: @howlger Gradle -> Refresh gradle project did not pull my updated jar from artifactory, I don't know why not. Thats's why I had to do >gradle eclipse

Comment: I've updated the4 question with additional info on the missing jar.